# Class "Branches" must implement a "__toString" method to be rendered in a "sfWidgetFormPropelJQueryAutocompleter" widget

Tags: php, symfony-1.2

what i need

- i need to render autocomplete widget in view

partial code php file
_work.php

```
 <!-- Branch -->
  <tr>
    <th>
      <?php echo $form['branch_code']->renderLabel(); ?>
    </th>
    <td>
      <?php echo $form['branch_code']->renderError(); ?>
      <?php echo $form['branch_code']->render(array('size' => '45')); ?>
      <select id="emp_list2" style="display: none;">
        <option></option>
      </select>
      &nbsp
      <a href="#" id="list-all2">[List all]</a>
      <br />
      <?php echo $form['branch_code']->renderHelp(); ?>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

branches.php

```
  class Branches extends BaseBranches
  {


   public function __toString()
  {
   return $this->getBranchCode();
   }
    }
```

**error:**

> Class "Branches" must implement a "__toString" method to be rendered
>   in a "sfWidgetFormPropelJQueryAutocompleter" widget

- i have tried to debug issue this piece of line code create error.
- any suggestion is most welcome

Comment: is `$this->getBranchCode()` returning a string?

Comment: i have tried to debug it is not rendering in branch class , if put die in workplace class it works

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that __toString() is returning a string, so $this->getBranchCode() should return a string as well.